# NodeJS regex test function generating range error

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a requirement to check if a specific string is a valid base64. After passing a very large valid base64 string, the test function is hitting a range error (maximum call stack size exceeded).

```
if (/^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)?$/.test(base64)) {
    // if valid base64 proceed, ...
}
```

How should I go about avoid hitting this error? Should I section the base64 string into smaller strings and test individually?

Comment: What is the size of the input string for which you get the error?

Comment: Frame challenge: why even test it? Why not just decode it and handle the error from the decoder?

Comment: Just testing whether characters are within the charset and whether the amount of padding characters doesn't suffice to check whether base64 is valid. A certain amount of padding also imposes restrictions on the characters your base64 may end with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are these rules to check:

1. At most two `=` symbols are allowed, and they should be at the very end of the input
2. All other characters should be alphanumeric or `+` or `/`.
3. The total input length must be a multiple of 4

The `([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*` part in your regex will make the regex engine use a stack slot for each occurrence of 4 characters -- to allow for backtracking -- which for an input of millions of characters will require stack space of the same order of magnitude.

To avoid this stack space requirement, you could perform the last check with a simple check in JavaScript: the string length modulo 4 should be 0.

So that leads to this code:

```js
function verifyBase64(base64) {
    return base64.length % 4 == 0 && /^[A-Za-z0-9+\/]*=?=?$/.test(base64);
}

let base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
base64 = base64.repeat(100000); 

console.log(verifyBase64(base64)); // true
console.log(verifyBase64(base64 + "=")); // false
console.log(verifyBase64(base64 + "ab==")); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well.
The answer from [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) is correct, but I wanted to expand with my solution:

```js
function isBase64(str) {
    try {
        // Try to decode the string
        const decoded = atob(str);

        // Encode the decoded string back to Base64
        const reencoded = btoa(decoded);

        // If the reencoded string is equal to the original string, it's Base64
        return reencoded === str;
    } catch (e) {
        // If an error occurs during decoding, it's not Base64
        return false;
    }
}

// Example usage:
const base64String = "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="; // Base64-encoded "Hello World"
const nonBase64String = "Hello, World!"; // Not Base64-encoded

console.log(isBase64(base64String)); // true
console.log(isBase64(nonBase64String)); // false
```

This function first tries to decode the string using atob. If the decoding is successful, it then encodes the decoded string back to Base64 using btoa and checks if the reencoded string matches the original string. If they match, the input is considered Base64; otherwise, it's not. If there's an error during decoding (e.g., for a non-Base64 string), it returns false.

This method should work well for both small and large strings without causing a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Note: This should work to replace this particular Regex intended to find if a string is base 64 encoded.
If you run into this problem with a different purpose regexp, the problem is recursivity, like mentioned in the selected answer.

The only solution is to try to find an alternative method to test your string.